# How to set time using segment controller in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone programming. Can anybody tell me that how to set time here using segment controller? In this below code 0.5 time is I have given but now I want set time using segment  controller. Example in segment controller I have taken like this 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.10, 0.20, 0.30 if I select any one of the number through segment controller like 0.10 it have set that number in place of 0.5. How can I do this?

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.5
                 target: self
                 selector: @selector(methodName:)
                 userInfo: nil
                 repeats: YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you select the new value, [`invalidate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) the old timer and start a new one.

Answer (score 0):

suppose for Example in segment controller you take like this 0.1,0.2,0.5,0.10,0.20,0.30 value then see bellow..

```
-(IBAction) segmentedControlIndexChanged{

  switch (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
      NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1
             target: self
             selector: @selector(methodName:)
             userInfo: nil
             repeats: YES];
      break;
    case 1:
      NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.2
             target: self
             selector: @selector(methodName:)
             userInfo: nil
             repeats: YES];
      break;
     case 2:
      NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.5
             target: self
             selector: @selector(methodName:)
             userInfo: nil
             repeats: YES];
      break;
     case 3:
      NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.10
             target: self
             selector: @selector(methodName:)
             userInfo: nil
             repeats: YES];
      break;
     case 4:
      NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.20
             target: self
             selector: @selector(methodName:)
             userInfo: nil
             repeats: YES];
      break;
    default:
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.30
             target: self
             selector: @selector(methodName:)
             userInfo: nil
             repeats: YES];
       break;

   }
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much giving replay.

Comment: Acctually what i want means i recording the voice i want give particular time for recording for that iam using segment controller if i select particular time means it has to record only how time iam giving that much it  have to record after that it has to stop that recording.How to do that

Comment: set one Variable in each segment and check With seg index taped and then stop recording sound as par @paras Joshi's answer he is correct and u need to just impliment your logic in above answer And in Your Question you asking for Time not for Recording and bla bla so please be more clear about your question and get relevant answer

Comment: yes dude @NitinGohel right and also here  use the title or value of segament with tag and set timer with it thanx...